# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. ExpressJs

Tags: jquery, ajax, express, cors, asp.net-web-api

I understand this has been asked before but I am having a cors issue even though I think I am setting the correct header on every request. I couldnt get the standard way of setting the headers in the middleware so I set them explicitly for each api method:

```
router.route('/books')
    .get(function(req, res){
        allowCORS(res);
        Repository.getAll().done(
            function(result) { res.json(result); }, 
            function(err) { res.send(err); }
        );  
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        allowCORS(res);
        Repository.save(req.body).done(
            function(object) { res.json(object); }, 
            function(err) { res.send(err); }
        );
});
```

and the allowCors method:

```
var allowCORS = function(res)
{ 
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'X-Requested-With,content-type');

    // Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in the requests sent
    // to the API (e.g. in case you use sessions)
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
}
```

This works for get and post BUT so far, for delete it does not work:

```
router.route('/books/:id')   
    .delete(function(req, res) {
        allowCORS(res);
        Repository.del({ _id: req.params.id }).done(
            function(result){ res.json(result); }, 
            function(err){ res.send(err); });   
    });
```

The above errors in the browser. 
What am I missing here? I am able to compose a delete request from Fiddler successfully but not from ajax script. The ajax looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
        url: url + '/' + id,
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: callback,
        error: errorCallback
        });
```

Comment: I have/ should have control over what requests I can make as the expressjs api is created by me... that is exactly the problem. If you read the question you'd know I can already POST and GET, I just cant DELTE

Answer (score 0):

You are close, you need to change the way you define your middleware a bit.

The order of defining the middleware is important in Node.  The code below basically allows CORS on all requests (`*`).  If you only wanted to allow it on `/books` you would do  `res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "/book");`

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

router.route('/books')
    .get(function(req, res){
        Repository.getAll().done(
            function(result) { res.json(result); }, 
            function(err) { res.send(err); }
        );  
    })
    .post(function(req, res) {
        Repository.save(req.body).done(
            function(object) { res.json(object); }, 
            function(err) { res.send(err); }
        );
});
```